# Запросы к серверу Python

Tags: python

На вот этот код:

```
import requests

url = "http://********:****/api/Sites?contractNumber=2222"

headers = {
    "apiKey": "****"
}

try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()# проверяем статус ответа HTTP
    print(response.content)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Connection error:", e)
```

выдаёт вот эту ошибку

```
Connection error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://********:***/api/Sites?contractNumber=2222
```

подскажите куда копать, вот пример в curl

```
Пример выполнения запроса, в котором указано значение для параметра contractNumber
curl --request GET \
  --header ’apiKey: 41c66fd22dcf4742b65e9f5ea5ebde1c’ \
  --url ’http://10.7.22.128:9002/api/Sites?contractNumber=2018-12/91&userName=crm-Ivanova-A-A’
```

Comment: У вас в curl и python разные строки запроса. В curl вы обращаетесь к `/api/Sites?contractNumber=2018-12/91&userName=crm-Ivanova-A-A`, а в `python` - к `/api/Sites?contractNumber=2222`. Вполне возможно, что без `userName` сервис не работает, вот и возвращает вам ошибку 400

Comment: значения из строки не имеет значения, curl из примера взят

Answer (score 0):

На сервере был указан доступ только с localhost.